# Cocoa NSUserDefaultsController: Multiple methods named 'save:' found

Tags: xcode, cocoa, compiler-warnings

This question has been asked in various forms on here before, but I cannot seem to figure out what the compiler is complaining about; there are no other `save:` methods in the `NSUserDefaultsController` class or any of its super classes.

The method in which this warning occurs is an `IBAction` attached to the `OK` button of my Preferences window.

I like no warnings so it's bothering me a bit; can anyone help get rid of it?

[image]

EDIT: as pointed out by @Peter, the compiler doesn't know that `sharedUserDefaultsController` returns an `NSUserDefaultsController` object.  This is fixed using:

```
   NSUserDefaultsController *userDefaultsController = [NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController];
   [userDefaultsController save:sender];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `sharedUserDefaultsController`, according to the documentation, is declared as

```
+ (id)sharedUserDefaultsController
```

So there's no way to know it's an `NSUserDefaultsController` here. Thus any `save` method could be addressed, I think.